# Firefox extension to automatically replace HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Are there any current firefox extensions which will replace all links on a page from **http://** to **https://** so the intended effect will be:

Click a link for:
http://mysite.com/Home.aspx

Firefox will actually request:
https://mysite.com/Home.aspx

Comment: Belongs to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin that will automatically use [HTTPS for a specific list of site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/229918/)s. I'm not aware of 1 that will attempt it automatically on every url as what would happen if the site wasn't available over SSL? Waiting for the request to time out before again making another HTTP request would cause delay for the user.

Comment: This plugin has very BAD PRIVACY agreement - they track you.

Comment: @Maxim Do you have any articles about it? I can't seem to find anything conclusive. Cheers.

Comment: I just was impressed by their privacy policy publicly available.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Download the Firefox-Addon https-everywhere: https://www.eff.org/files/https-everywhere-latest.xpi

**2.** Create your own rulesset and you may use the source code of this plugin if the license applies to your use case

Comment: This plugin has very BAD PRIVACY agreement - they track you.